# Retrieve marker from a Matplotlib Collection

Tags: python, matplotlib, markers

I'm looking to retrieve the marker type from a Matplotlib collection.

I can retrieve what seems like every other attribute from the collection by calling collection.get_linestyle(), collection.get_linewidth(), etc, but it seems there is not an option for marker. 
I am also able to retrieve a marker type from a matplotline.line.line2d.

Is there a way to retrieve the marker type from a collection?

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE]? It is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you can retrieve the type of marker used in a `PathCollection` (i.e. in a scatter plot). This information is not stored as such in the collection. However, the markers are stored as `Path` objects (hence the name of the collection).

For example:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
a = ax.scatter([0],[0],marker='v')
b = ax.scatter([1],[0],marker='s')

a.get_paths()
```

> (Path(array([[-6.123234e-17, -5.000000e-01],
>           [ 5.000000e-01,  5.000000e-01],
>           [-5.000000e-01,  5.000000e-01],
>           [-6.123234e-17, -5.000000e-01]]), array([ 1,  2,  2, 79], dtype=uint8)),)

As you can surmise, the triangle marker is defined by 4 points (notice that the last point is equal to the first so the shape is closed).

```
b.get_paths()
```

> (Path(array([[-0.5, -0.5],
>           [ 0.5, -0.5],
>           [ 0.5,  0.5],
>           [-0.5,  0.5],
>           [-0.5, -0.5]]), array([ 1,  2,  2,  2, 79], dtype=uint8)),)

Conversely, a square marker is defined by 5 points (last point == first point).

If the goal is to copy this marker to a new collection, you should be able to copy the Path object over. If you need somehow to detect which marker is used, you could keep a list of Paths objects (generated as above) and compare the returned Path to that list.

Comment: Wow thank you Diziet, this is really helpful!! I would like to be able to compare marker types in collections and lines. Is there a similar method for lines where the output is a path such as this one?